# How do I build an XML file?

Tags: ruby, xml, excel

I'm building up an XML template to export to Excel.

I would like to do something like this:

```
<Worksheet ss:Name=<%= page.title %>>
```

to give the worksheet the name of the page title but this does not work.

If I do:

```
<Worksheet ss:Name="sheet1">
```

it all works.

How can I assign the page title to the worksheet name?

Comment: what's the file name of the XML template you're trying to render?

Comment: for now just called `xls.xml.erb`

Comment: You should use `@page` instead of just `page` in both controller and view.

Comment: Using page as its already in a loop which pipes it to `page`

Comment: I assume "This does not work" means you have loaded into Excel and not seen your title on the worksheet tab? What is the actual output you currently get from the template for this element?

Comment: "This does not work" means it exports but when opening in excel theres just one blank sheet. Whereas when explicitly assigning "sheet1" the xml is compiled properly and all rendering is done correctly except for the sheet name thats "sheet1"

Comment: Why not use something made to generate XML, like [Nokogiri::XML::Builder](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html)?It will handle the encoding and correct tag open/closing for you. See the Nokogiri tutorial for tips on generating XML also. You can use ERB but you assume the task of making sure all tags are handled and content encodings are right. XML isn't a flexible forgiving format like HTML so I find it easier to rely on something that deals with the esoterica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that you're not wrapping `page.title` in quotes, so Excel can't properly parse the file. You should add them just outside the erb code:

```
<Worksheet ss:Name="<%= page.title %>">
```